# Linux device driver functional testing

Tags: testing, linux-device-driver, functional-testing

For the development of device driver in linux kernel, is there any general-purpose and automated test suite to cover the basic/minimal functionality of a specific kind of device driver? For example, if we test NIC driver, we can make sure that the basic function like send/receive packets and network configuration can be handled in a correct way. As for some unique functions of a specific device driver, we do not need to pay too much attention to it and only assure that its minimal functionality is correct. I assume this kind of test suite should leverage high level applications to verify functional correctness of the device driver instead of low level unit test. 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Among other things, [Autotest](http://autotest.github.com/) is worth looking at. I used the tests it provides to check the drivers related to wireless networking some time ago.

Apart from that, the tests from the [Linux Test Project](http://ltp.sourceforge.net/) could also be useful here.